# Como fazer a configuração correta do proguard?

Tags: java, android, proguard

Como fazer a configuração correta do `proguard`, trazendo melhor segurança, menor tamanho e excluindo classes quando desejar ou quando criar problemas?

Basicamente habilito as configurações padrões em alterando `minifyEnabled` para  `true`

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

O que já faz o básico. Agora o que fazer para otimizar? A utilização do proguard ?

Answer (score -1):

adicine para diminuir o tamanho do apk e descartar as classes e arquivos não utilizados

```
shrinkResources verdadeira
         minifyEnabled verdadeira
```

edite o arquivo

adicionando 
    #please KEEP ALL THE NAMES
    -keepnames class ** { *; }

para que não seja aplicado o embaralhamento na classe